# Difference between createSelector and createDraftSafeSelector API in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, reselect, immer.js

`createSelector` mentioned at https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

> `createSelector` API, which generates memoized selector functions.
> createSelector accepts one or more "input" selectors, which extract
> values from arguments, and an "output" selector that receives the
> extracted values and should return a derived value. If the generated
> selector is called multiple times, the output will only be
> recalculated when the extracted values have changed.

`createDraftSafeSelector` mentioned at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector

> `createDraftSafeSelector` allows to create selectors that can
> safely be used inside of `createReducer` and `createSlice` reducers with
> Immer-powered mutable logic. When used with plain state values, the
> selector will still memoize normally based on the inputs. But, when
> used with Immer draft values, the selector will err on the side of
> recalculating the results, just to be safe.

I am new to [react](https://reactjs.org/) and [redux](https://redux.js.org/) design patterns so could not understand the difference and purpose of `createDraftSafeSelector`.

What is the difference in both API? What can be an example to understand the difference?

Answer (score 3):

A selector created with `createDraftSafeSelector` can be used safely within `createReducer` or `createSlice` reducers, which is not possible with `createSelector`, as that one solely relies on object reference equality.

A selector created with `createSelector` would always return the same result for one reducer call even if you modified the state in-between.

Most people never use selectors in reducers, so you will probably never need it.

Answer (score 0):

See the real-world usage of the draft safe selector, [interactionsBucketsSelectors.selectById(state.interactionsBuckets, convPk)](https://github.com/berty/berty/blob/v2.390.0/js/packages/redux/reducers/messenger.reducer.ts#L160)

We can pass the draft state of immer.js in the draft safe selector in RTK case reducer.

The `selectById` draft safe selector created in [getSelectors()](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.8.2/packages/toolkit/src/entities/state_selectors.ts#L58).

`createDraftSafeSelector` is a wrapper for `createSelector`, it not only supports the general JS object state that `createSelector` can handle, but also supports the draft State of immerjs, see [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.8.2/packages/toolkit/src/createDraftSafeSelector.ts):

```
import { current, isDraft } from 'immer'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

/**
 * "Draft-Safe" version of `reselect`'s `createSelector`:
 * If an `immer`-drafted object is passed into the resulting selector's first argument,
 * the selector will act on the current draft value, instead of returning a cached value
 * that might be possibly outdated if the draft has been modified since.
 * @public
 */
export const createDraftSafeSelector: typeof createSelector = (
  ...args: unknown[]
) => {
  const selector = (createSelector as any)(...args)
  const wrappedSelector = (value: unknown, ...rest: unknown[]) =>
    selector(isDraft(value) ? current(value) : value, ...rest)
  return wrappedSelector as any
}
```

You may also want to see these two [test cases](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.8.2/packages/toolkit/src/tests/createDraftSafeSelector.test.ts) about the difference between `createSelector` and `createDraftSafeSelector`.

If you don't pass the draft state of immerjs to selectors, you don't need to use `createDraftSafeSelector`.